# Everything uninstalled by `apt purge openssl` on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, openssl

In process of downgrading `openssl`, trying to first remove its current version I did `sudo apt-get purge openssl`. Now it seems it has uninstalled EVERYTHING ON MY SYSTEM! openssl, octave... etc. I can't even read a hard disk or a pen drive now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out somehow.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

seems to have returned everything I lost.